# Alterar o fundo do header de apenas uma página ionic

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic

Tem um projeto `ionic` e preciso que a `ion-header-bar` de apenas uma página fique com um background diferente do restante da aplicação.

Home (HTML)

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">

<ion-content id="home" align="center" class="bg-home">
    <div class="row bg-green">
        <div class="col">
            <img src="img/logo-prov02.png" class="login-logo" style="width: 35%; padding-bottom: 5px">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-50" style="padding-top: 15px">
            <a href="#/app/create-repass">                  
                <img src="img/icon-repass-green.png" class="login-logo" style="width: 35%; padding-bottom: 5px"><br>
                <span class="font-green">Repassar</span><br>
                <span class="font-gray">Crie anúncios para repassar seus veículos</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-50" style="padding-top: 15px">
            <a href="#/app/create-preferences">
                <img src="img/icon-preferences-green.png" class="login-logo" style="width: 35%; padding-bottom: 5px"><br>
                <span class="font-green">Preferências</span><br>
                <span class="font-gray">Preferências de busca para achar o veículo certo</span>                 
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-50" style="padding-top: 15px">
            <a ng-click="showSearch()">
                <img src="img/icon-search-green.png" class="login-logo" style="width: 35%; padding-bottom: 5px"><br>
                <span class="font-green">Buscar</span><br>
                <span class="font-gray">Busque veículos em nossa base de dados</span>                   
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-50" style="padding-top: 15px">
            <a href="#/app/list-user-repass">
                <img src="img/icon-favorites-green.png" class="login-logo" style="width: 35%; padding-bottom: 5px"><br>
                <span class="font-green">Favoritos</span><br>
                <span class="font-gray">Acesse seus anúncios favoritos</span>                   
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</ion-content>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar nesse processo?

Comment: Ao que parece, salvo equívoco, seu css está declarado direto nas tags, onde a precedência se sobressai. Mesmo que defina uma folha de estilos no head (como em minha resposta), as regras que vão serem aplicadas, serão essas que estão direto nas tags.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode definir, uma folha de estilo, específica, para sua página com as regras que deseja. Colocando a referência ao arquivo no `head` da página que deseja aplicar a regra.

Dá para fazer com javascript, colocando o estilo direto nas tags ou ...

Depende do contexto. Espero que ajude qualquer coisa comenta e ajustamos.

suaPagina.php

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="novaRegra.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="ion-header-bar"></header>  
</body>
```

novaRegra.css

```
.ion-header-bar{
    background-color: #777777;
}
```

Comment: ja tentei varias opções e nenhuma deu certo, tentei sobrescrever o ion navabar, mas ele não funciona.

Comment: @EdinhoRodrigues são tantas variáveis do que pode estar acontecendo, que fica inviável, eu colocar uma sugestão. Uma ideia para começarmos é editar a pergunta, e colocar os códigos do html e css que está usando, o trecho relevante, vem por esse caminho.

Comment: OK, vou colocar os códigos